# get value from @Model inside jquery script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model

How can I get value from `@Model` inside jquery script. I want to get some property  by index(determined by row selection in my custom table)   from my Model which is `IEnumerable<T>` . I don't want to show this property in table and do something like cell `.val()`

for example :

```
var selectedRow = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)) - 1;
```

and I want something like

```
 @Model.ElementAt(selectedRow).SomeProperty
```

inside script

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

@Model is a .NET object (server-side), your JQuery scripts are running client-side and operate on JavaScript objects. You can't directly access server-side .NET objects from client-side code - you'll need to have some JSON serialization of your model (or maybe just the properties you're interested in). Then inside a script you can do something like

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

to get your model into a JavaScript variable, then access everything through "model".

Comment: This is great! now I just need to query my json, but this approach is very neat.

Comment: ASP.NET Core syntax is @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))

Answer (score -1):

use html5 data attributes in your view.. to make your model available in html
then access them via js