# Access MVC 3 Razor object value from JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I’m trying to embed a JQuery string within a Razor object that access it's property....something like this:

```
var propertyID = $(this).attr('id');  
var modelData = “@Model.InitialHistory.” + propertyID;
```

modelData should look something like this: @Model.InitialHistory.Property_1;

(if i type @Model.InitialHistory.Property_1; in my code it works fine, just need to dynamically select the razor property)

is something like this even possible or am I going to have to create an ajax call?

thanks!

Comment: you can't mix server-side and client-side script like that. You'll likely have to use ajax for that.

Comment: You should put all the data from your razor object into (a) javascript variable(s). Then dynamically select it client-side, or use AJAX like you mention above. JavaScript cannot interact with Razor directly.

Comment: Please look into this article: [get value from @Model inside jquery script][1]

Hope this helps

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770578/get-value-from-model-inside-jquery-script

Comment: I've found Ajax to be the best solution.

Comment: Oh wow....didn't think of that, putting the @Model in a JQuery object - great idea!

However, I tried that and got this error:

    A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies......"

At this point it seems to me making an Ajax call is probably a better "solution" (the Model I have has about 150+ columns of data which leaves more room for error when serializing to JSON)

much thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't!

javascript-jQuery is client side scripting, while razor is server side code.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make Model.InitialHistory a list, and loop through that in the view.