# How to get to Model or Viewbag Variables in a Script Tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

*Vs'12 asp.net C# MVC4 - Int.Appl.Template EF Code First*

Here is my very simple `Script`

```
<script class="TractsScript">

     $('#Add').click(function (e) {

         var val = @ViewBag.ForSection;
         alert(val);

     });
</script>
```

**As per example I am wanting to simply set a variable in my `script` or USE a `Viewbag.` or `Model.`**

I haven't been able to find an answer in any of the following forums: [StckTrace1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript),[StackTraceBetterAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770578/get-value-from-model-inside-jquery-script)

Other Things i have tried:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
alert(model.Sections);
alert(@ViewBag.ForSection);
```

Comment: If you don't have any circular references in your model, you might try something like `var val = @new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)`.

Comment: Is this script in line into the View?

Comment: @Fals I'm sorry I'm still new to all of this, if you are asing if the script is in the same document as the View, then yes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this way, providing Json or Any other variable:

1) For exemple, in the controller, you can use `Json.NET` to provide `Json` to the `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.Number = 10;
ViewBag.FooObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo { Text = "Im a foo." });
```

2) In the `View`, put the script like this at the bottom of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number = parseInt(@ViewBag.Number); //Accessing the number from the ViewBag
    alert("Number is: " + number);
    var model = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.FooObj); //Accessing the Json Object from ViewBag
    alert("Text is: " + model.Text);
</script>
```

Comment: But when I am trying to access @ViewBag.Number it is showing blank value..

Comment: @HrishikeshTT Are you sure you are at the same controller context? Viewbag lives only with the same context of the controller and the called view.

Comment: Yes I am sure that the script call is in the same controller context. And another doubt is, can we access ViewData in the same manner ?

Answer (score 31):

What you have should work. It depends on the type of data you are setting i.e. if it's a string value you need to make sure it's in quotes e.g.

```
var val = '@ViewBag.ForSection';
```

---

If it's an integer you need to *parse* it as one i.e.

```
var val = parseInt(@ViewBag.ForSection);
```

Comment: if I ran `var attTwo = '@ViewBag.ForSection';` and then `alert(attTwo);` I receive an Alert with "" (*Null*) value.

Comment: Like I said "*It depends on the type of data you are setting*" - what type of data is `ForSection`?

Comment: It is set in my Controller and For my `Viewbag.` should be of type `Integer`. My Model.Sections However is parsed to String.

Comment: sorry man still not working error: `CS0103: The name 'Viewbag' does not exist in the current context` when using `var vals = parseInt('@Viewbag.ForSection');` and if i write the same code without `@` i get result `NaN`

Comment: In Fal's answer he isn't using the `'` around the Variable. This worked thanks for your help +1

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle I thought you would have to wrap it in `'` as `parseInt` expects a string! I wasn't in front of a computer so couldn't test.

Comment: I found James's answer to be correct.  I had an integer id in my view bag.  var mystrid='@ViewBag.id',  var myintid=@ViewBag.id.   mystrid had no value, myintid had the integer value for id.

Answer (score 5):

try this method

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function set(value) {
        return value;
    }

    alert(set(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Message)))); // Message set from controller
    alert(set(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.UrMessage))));

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotation marks (`'`):

```
var val = '@ViewBag.ForSection';
alert(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing this

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

You're probably getting a JSON string, and not a JavaScript object.

You need to parse it in to an object:

```
var model = JSON.parse(model); //or $.parseJSON() since if jQuery is included
console.log(model.Sections);
```