# while using @htm.raw getting Syntax error "returns mark up that is not html encoded"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am studying about passing [multiple models to view by using various methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC). However when I wrote this line:

```
var allFaculties = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Faculties"]));
```

I am getting a syntax error:

> returns mark up that is not html encoded

How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE**
I am using MVC4 ,is there any additional changes i have to do.

Comment: Show us the ViewData["Faculties"]) content

Comment: Do this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872720/how-to-get-to-model-or-viewbag-variables-in-a-script-tag/18873175#18873175

Comment: @ Fals i did everything as per the link ,dittoo    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC

Comment: Answer is provided in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872720/how-to-get-to-model-or-viewbag-variables-in-a-script-tag/18873175#18873175